# How do I save the Checked property state to Properties.Settings When using WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I'm converting a program from WinForms to WPF. There seems to be a lot of unnecessary syntax changes. But the one I'm having trouble with is saving the "checked" or "unchecked" status to Properties.Settings. In WinForms I used:

```
    private void chkBackup_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = chkBackup.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

There doesn't seem to be an Event for "CheckedChanged" in WPF, So I'm trying:

```
    private void chkBackup_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = (chkBackup.IsChecked == true);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    private void chkBackup_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = (chkBackup.IsChecked == false);
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

I get no errors with this, but when I uncheck the checkBox, the settings aren't changed. Please help. What am I doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it doesn't work"? Are those methods not being executed? Is the IsChecked property not what you'd expect?

Comment: I have the setting set to "True" as the default. But when the box is unchecked, the settings remain at "True"

Comment: To address 2 of the answers below. Yes, I do have the XAML handlers in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a different expression each time. In the checked event you're using `chkBackup.IsChecked == true` which evaluates to true if the box is checked and false otherwise.

In the unchecked event you're using `chkBackup.IsChecked == false` which evaluates to true if the box isn't checked and false otherwise.

What you're interested in is if the box is checked or not. The expression to use for this is `chkBackup.IsChecked == true`. Your current solution will always save `true`.

Comment: That make no sense to me. But you're absolutely right! When I make the change you suggest, it works exactly as desired. Can you PLEASE explain why this is the case?

Comment: When the checkbox is checked the expression `chkBackup.IsChecked == true` evaluates to true, because it is true that it's checked. When the checkbox isn't checked the expression `chkBackup.IsChecked == false` evaluates to true because it is true that it isn't checked.

Comment: OK, now that makes sense. Thanks Matthew!

Answer (score 0):

you are using the Settings object correctly (from the code you provided), so maybe you need to attach the Checked/Unchecked event handlers.... ([MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
<!-- in your xaml -->    
<CheckBox Checked="OnChecked" Unchecked="OnUnchecked"/>

//in your code-behind....
myCheckbox.OnChecked += myHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Are you hooking up your handlers in XAML?

```
<CheckBox Name="chkbox"
          Content="Some Checkbox"
          Checked="chkBackup_Checked"
          Unchecked="chkBackup_Unchecked" />
```

---

If you want it to be a little more streamlined, you could do something like this:

```
<CheckBox Name="chkbox"
          Content="Some Checkbox"
          Checked="chkBackup_CheckChanged"
          Unchecked="chkBackup_CheckChanged" />


private void chkBackup_CheckChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = chkBackup.IsChecked;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found, that in WPF you can use regular bools to save a value. It's inconvenient, but it works. :/

```
private void chkBackup_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = True;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}

private void chkBackup_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Backup = False;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

and to check if it's checked, you can use

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.Backup == False) 
{
    //enter code here
}
```